# Tomcat - Address already in use but no process

Tags: windows, tomcat, port

I was having an issue with Tomcat 10.1 where I was always getting "Address already in use", but checking `netstat -ano | findstr ":<port>"` showed no bound processes.

Answer (score 0):

What I found out was that if you are running Win 10 + Hyper-V + Docker for Windows; Windows will reserve a whole lot of ports. So you have to use a port outside those ranges or you can netsh to exclude a port range.